# for Inkscape scripting, what is the difference between "object-set-attribute" and "object-set-property"?

Tags: vector-graphics, inkscape

```
$ inkscape --action-list
...
object-set-attribute:  Set or update an attribute on selected objects. Usage: object-set-attribute:attribute name, attribute value;
object-set-property :  Set or update a property on selected objects. Usage: object-set-property:property name, property value;
...
```

What is the difference between an "attribute" and a "property", if any? If they are the same thing, shouldn't that be clarified somewhere?

Can either of these be used to specify text in Inkscape, which seems to be neither an attribute nor a property, but rather the inner content of an XML element?

If not, how would you script text replacement in Inkscape? You could use "sed" or some XML tool to edit the file directly, but it seems like there should be some Inkscape-specific way to do it. If there isn't, isn't that a problem?

Comment: As for the difference between properties and attributes: https://github.com/elm/html/blob/master/properties-vs-attributes.md